# Can I use a portable air conditioner with a casement window?

Tags: windows, air-conditioning

[image]

My apartment has windows like this, where they rotate out upon a vertical hinge. I live in Seattle, so I can't rely on an evaporative A/C unit because the humidity is too high. And all the portable vented A/C's I've seen require either vertically sliding or horizontally sliding windows to mount the vent hose. Do I have any options for getting an A/C to work with this style window?

Comment: The term to google is "casement window air conditioner"

Answer (score 1):

The easy, but ugly solution is to cut a sheet of plywood that will fill the entire opening, and cut a hole in that to attach the AC exaust hose.  Or cut the plywood to fit in beside the exaust hose, whichever is easier.

Then insulate and seal the crap out of it with foam boards and metal tape.

I would recommend avoiding portable AC if you can get one that will fit the window though - I have 2 of them, and they do not work as well as one that sits in the window.  They take more power and take twice as long to cool the room.

Depending on the window, you might be able to easily pop the window out of the frame to fit a normal window AC, with plywood to fill the rest of the opening.

Comment: Rather than plywood, try plexiglass.

Comment: +1 for "might be able to...pop the window out". I'm not sure what the OP is willing to spend...but it might be possible for him to convince management to let him replace the window with a double hung, or something that would allow him to have a proper window AC install. They might balk at something that would look unsightly. If it's a heavily administered and managed apt, it may not be possible, but if OP has direct contact with the owner, I wouldn't be remotely surprised if paying for a replacement window could be deducted from his rent (which is the question I would lead with if it were me).

Comment: If the window cannot be removed to create an entire opening mount for the exhaust hose, AND if the window will open enough to handle the hose placed "radially," the OP could create a wedge shape at the top and bottom, with a flat panel on the chord of the arc made by the window. That flat panel would then have the exhaust hose hole/mount.